# pushViewController:animated: doesn't fully animate current controller out of bounds

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` thats width is 255 and the `rootViewController` is a `UITableViewController` that is of the same width. The problem is that when I *push* a new view controller, the current `rootViewController` animates about 1/3 of the way off screen and then stays visible while the new controller comes in and then it disappears. If I set `animated` to `NO` it works fine, but I need to animate it. There isn't anything fancy going on in the code, it is a simple `push/pop` setup when switching controllers. I added a video below to show you what it looks like. I put borders on the navigation controller (blue) and table view (orange). The code that does the push/pop is:

```
if ([[self.menuNavigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[TeamMenuViewController class]])
{
    [self.menuNavigationController pushViewController:self.teamsViewController animated:YES];
}
else
{
    [self.menuNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to show your code.

Comment: Did you ever fix this behavior to get your vc to fully animate off?

Comment: The selected answer gave me what I needed. I just gave it a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `viewController.view` that is being pushed on has a transparent background.  The default `UINavigationController` animation in iOS 7 and 8 has an overlap effect.

Comment: So how would you fix this to kill the overlap effect?

Comment: I ended up setting a background color on the incoming vc